# perl: sliding window search along mesh array

Tags: arrays, perl, mesh, sliding-window

I am ultimately trying to combine three arrays of letters using [`List::MoreUtils::mesh`](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#mesh_ARRAY1_ARRAY2_[_ARRAY3_..._]), so that I can then compare each position among the sequences. 
For example, if I have three files that look like:

```
    >file_1 
    TAGCTAGCCAGC-T
```

the first comparison would be between TTT (this would count as no substitution). If the first letters are TAA, this would count as a substitution. The first challenge is to get the three corresponding letters together to compare.

Here is my code so far:

```
    use strict; 
    use warnings; 
    use List::MoreUtils qw{mesh}; 

    open (SEQ_ONE, "<", "/path/to/file_1.txt") or die $!; 
    open (SEQ_TWO, "<", "/path/to/file_2.txt") or die $!; 
    open (REFERENCE, "<", "/path/to/reference_sequence.txt") or die $!; 

    my @first; 
    my @second; 
    my @reference; 
    my @combined; 
    my $sequence; 
    my $secondsequence; 
    my $thirdsequence; 
    my $windowsize = 3; 
    my $step = 3; 

    while (my $line = <SEQ_ONE>){ 
            chomp $line; 
            if ($line !~ /^>+/) { 
                    $sequence .= $line; 
            } 
            @first = split //, $sequence; 
     }

    while (my $secondline = <SEQ_TWO>){ 
            chomp $secondline; 
            if ($secondline !~ /^>+/){
                     $secondsequence .= $secondline; 
            }
            @second = split //, $secondsequence; 
    } 

    while (my $thirdline = <REFERENCE>){ 
            chomp $thirdline; 
            if ($thirdline !~ /^>+/){ 
                    $thirdsequence .= $thirdline; 
            } 
            @reference = split //, $thirdsequence; 
    } 

    @combined = mesh @reference, @first, @second; 
    my $list = "@combined"; 

    for (my $windowstart = 0; $windowstart <= (length($list) - $windowsize); $windowstart += $step){ 
            my $windowSeq = substr($list, $windowstart, $windowsize); 
            print $windowSeq, "\n"; 
    }
```

This seems to break up the letters in chunks of letters, alternating in lengths of 2 and 1 letters. Output for the above code looks something like:

```
    T T
     T 
    A A
     A 
    G G
     G
```

I have experimented with different window and step sizes, but I still can't get the desired output of separate three letters at a time. I am close, just not quite there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your line `my $list = "@combined";` has the array interpolated _with spaces added between characters_.  I am not sure that you want that -- any sequence of three characters then must have one or two spaces.  It seems to me that you want `my $list = join '', @combined;`.  Btw, I do not understand your problem description at all.

Comment: Hi zdim, Thanks for your answer! How should I improve my question, if at all? Maybe I could just simplify it...Thanks again.

Comment: It is good that you gave all code and described the problem!  However, you used the word "_mesh_" and I thought that you were referring to some technique in your field.  (I added the link, I hope you don't mind.)  Then, with "_count as substitution_" I thought you meant computing, until it downed on me that it's biology. I'd suggest that you avoid terms from your field, and if you need them explain them briefly. Also, while I do see the problem (extra spaces in strings) it is not clear from your description.  So it's all about how descriptions are worded. My $.02.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I try to be as descriptive as possible, without being OVERLY descriptive. Proving just the right amount of information is always a very fine line to walk it seems, especially since I am a biologist talking to computer programmers! :) Thanks again zdim. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I meant to say -- firstly, it's a good question. You clearly put thought and effort in and provide a lot.  As for writing effectively here, it's not that easy. I still struggle a lot :). Sometimes I'm in disbelief when I read my text after a little while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `my $list = "@combined";` produces a string which contains array elements and spaces added between them. This completely throws off `substr` processing below. Double-quoting an array (`"@array"`) is a convenience so that when printed it is easier to read.  Here you want

```
my $list = join '', @combined;
```